# Function blocks used in MD drive cannot be used in AD drive

Tags: robotics, servo, injection-molding

I program Schneider PLC and Machine Expert program
Normally I was using Schneider's SD or MD type drivers but now I need to do this program with AD driver but my function blocks are not working.

For SD and MD;

This is the library I use. MP_Calc.FB_MinimumTimeCalculator

Comment: You've asked on the wrong site, I'd say. Try
1. https://community.se.com/t5/c-krefy84679/EcoStruxure%2525E2%252584%2525A2+Machine+Expert/pd-p/ecostruxure-machine-expert, 2.  https://community.se.com/t5/Machine-Automation-Forum/bd-p/machine-automation-forum, 3. https://mrplc.com, 4. https://www.plctalk.net/.